# Numpy/Python performing terribly vs. Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Novice programmer here.  I'm writing a program that analyzes the relative spatial locations of points (cells).  The program gets boundaries and cell type off an array with the x coordinate in column 1, y coordinate in column 2, and cell type in column  3.  It then checks each cell for cell type and appropriate distance from the bounds. If it passes, it then calculates its distance from each other cell in the array and if the distance is within a specified analysis range it adds it to an output array at that distance.

My cell marking program is in wxpython so I was hoping to develop this program in python as well and eventually stick it into the GUI.  Unfortunately right now python takes ~20 seconds to run the core loop on my machine while MATLAB can do ~15 loops/second.  Since I'm planning on doing 1000 loops (with a randomized comparison condition) on ~30 cases times several exploratory analysis types this is not a trivial difference.

I tried running a profiler and array calls are 1/4 of the time, almost all of the rest is unspecified loop time.

Here is the python code for the main loop:

```
for basecell in range (0, cellnumber-1):
    if firstcelltype == np.array((cellrecord[basecell,2])):
        xloc=np.array((cellrecord[basecell,0]))
        yloc=np.array((cellrecord[basecell,1]))
        xedgedist=(xbound-xloc)
        yedgedist=(ybound-yloc)
        if xloc>excludedist and xedgedist>excludedist and yloc>excludedist and    yedgedist>excludedist:
            for comparecell in range (0, cellnumber-1):
                if secondcelltype==np.array((cellrecord[comparecell,2])):
                    xcomploc=np.array((cellrecord[comparecell,0]))
                    ycomploc=np.array((cellrecord[comparecell,1]))
                    dist=math.sqrt((xcomploc-xloc)**2+(ycomploc-yloc)**2)
                    dist=round(dist)
                    if dist>=1 and dist<=analysisdist:
                         arraytarget=round(dist*analysisdist/intervalnumber)
                         addone=np.array((spatialraw[arraytarget-1]))
                         addone=addone+1
                         targetcell=arraytarget-1
                         np.put(spatialraw,[targetcell,targetcell],addone)
```

Here is the matlab code for the main loop:

```
for basecell = 1:cellnumber;
    if firstcelltype==cellrecord(basecell,3);
         xloc=cellrecord(basecell,1);
         yloc=cellrecord(basecell,2);
         xedgedist=(xbound-xloc);
         yedgedist=(ybound-yloc);
         if (xloc>excludedist) && (yloc>excludedist) && (xedgedist>excludedist) && (yedgedist>excludedist);
             for comparecell = 1:cellnumber;
                 if secondcelltype==cellrecord(comparecell,3);
                     xcomploc=cellrecord(comparecell,1);
                     ycomploc=cellrecord(comparecell,2);
                     dist=sqrt((xcomploc-xloc)^2+(ycomploc-yloc)^2);
                     if (dist>=1) && (dist<=100.4999);
                         arraytarget=round(dist*analysisdist/intervalnumber);
                         spatialsum(1,arraytarget)=spatialsum(1,arraytarget)+1;
                    end
                end
            end            
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: That gave me roughly 25% improvement, thanks.

Comment: Are you certain that your two routines are giving *the same* results (i.e. that they are both performing the computation correctly)?

Comment: Yep, I'm checking the spatialsum/spatialraw (just noticed I named them differently.)  They're both adding correctly.

Comment: BUG: Use range(cellnumber), python excludes the upper limit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are some ways to speed up your python code.

**First:** Don't make np arrays when you are only storing one value. You do this many times over in your code. For instance,

```
if firstcelltype == np.array((cellrecord[basecell,2])):
```

can just be

```
 if firstcelltype == cellrecord[basecell,2]:
```

I'll show you why with some timeit statements:

```
>>> timeit.Timer('x = 111.1').timeit()
0.045882196294822819
>>> t=timeit.Timer('x = np.array(111.1)','import numpy as np').timeit()
0.55774970267830071
```

That's an order of magnitude in difference between those calls.

**Second:** The following code:

```
arraytarget=round(dist*analysisdist/intervalnumber)
addone=np.array((spatialraw[arraytarget-1]))
addone=addone+1
targetcell=arraytarget-1
np.put(spatialraw,[targetcell,targetcell],addone)
```

can be replaced with

```
arraytarget=round(dist*analysisdist/intervalnumber)-1
spatialraw[arraytarget] += 1
```

**Third:** You can get rid of the sqrt as Philip mentioned by squaring `analysisdist` beforehand. However, since you use `analysisdist` to get `arraytarget`, you might want to create a separate variable, `analysisdist2` that is the square of analysisdist and use that for your comparison.

**Fourth:** You are looking for cells that match `secondcelltype` every time you get to that point rather than finding those one time and using the list over and over again. You could define an array:

```
comparecells = np.where(cellrecord[:,2]==secondcelltype)[0]
```

and then replace

```
for comparecell in range (0, cellnumber-1):
    if secondcelltype==np.array((cellrecord[comparecell,2])):
```

with

```
for comparecell in comparecells:
```

**Fifth:** Use [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/). It is a JIT compiler. Matlab has a built-in JIT compiler if you're using a somewhat recent version. This should speed-up your code a bit.

**Sixth:** If the code still isn't fast enough after all previous steps, then you should try vectorizing your code. It shouldn't be too difficult. Basically, the more stuff you can have in numpy arrays the better. Here's my try at vectorizing:

```
basecells = np.where(cellrecord[:,2]==firstcelltype)[0]
xlocs = cellrecord[basecells, 0]
ylocs = cellrecord[basecells, 1]
xedgedists = xbound - xloc
yedgedists = ybound - yloc
whichcells = np.where((xlocs>excludedist) & (xedgedists>excludedist) & (ylocs>excludedist) & (yedgedists>excludedist))[0]
selectedcells = basecells[whichcells]
comparecells = np.where(cellrecord[:,2]==secondcelltype)[0]
xcomplocs = cellrecords[comparecells,0]
ycomplocs = cellrecords[comparecells,1]
analysisdist2 = analysisdist**2
for basecell in selectedcells:
    dists = np.round((xcomplocs-xlocs[basecell])**2 + (ycomplocs-ylocs[basecell])**2)
    whichcells = np.where((dists >= 1) & (dists <= analysisdist2))[0]
    arraytargets = np.round(dists[whichcells]*analysisdist/intervalnumber) - 1
    for target in arraytargets:
        spatialraw[target] += 1
```

You can probably take out that inner for loop, but you have to be careful because some of the elements of arraytargets could be the same. Also, I didn't actually try out all of the code, so there could be a bug or typo in there. Hopefully, it gives you a good idea of how to do this. Oh, one more thing. You make `analysisdist/intervalnumber` a separate variable to avoid doing that division over and over again.

Comment: Also, if aren't running your code inside of a function, then that should give you a speed-up as well. Alex Martelli mentions this in many of his posts and I've found it to be quite true.

Comment: So far tested 1-4 and Justin, Juri and Philip's suggestions and have a ~3x speed increase.  Going to have a look at pysco now.  Thanks for all the suggestions guys.

Comment: @Nissl, does that mean that you were able to get it down to 5 seconds from 20 with the range -> xrange change as well? Do you mind sharing how low you get it down to in the end? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure about the slowness of python but you Matlab code can be HIGHLY optimized.  Nested for-loops tend to have horrible performance issues.  You can replace the inner loop with a vectorized function ... as below:

```
for basecell = 1:cellnumber;
    if firstcelltype==cellrecord(basecell,3);
         xloc=cellrecord(basecell,1);
         yloc=cellrecord(basecell,2);
         xedgedist=(xbound-xloc);
         yedgedist=(ybound-yloc);
         if (xloc>excludedist) && (yloc>excludedist) && (xedgedist>excludedist) && (yedgedist>excludedist);
%             for comparecell = 1:cellnumber;
%                 if secondcelltype==cellrecord(comparecell,3);
%                     xcomploc=cellrecord(comparecell,1);
%                     ycomploc=cellrecord(comparecell,2);
%                     dist=sqrt((xcomploc-xloc)^2+(ycomploc-yloc)^2);
%                     if (dist>=1) && (dist<=100.4999);
%                         arraytarget=round(dist*analysisdist/intervalnumber);
%                         spatialsum(1,arraytarget)=spatialsum(1,arraytarget)+1;
%                    end
%                end
%            end
         %replace with:
        secondcelltype_mask = secondcelltype == cellrecord(:,3);
        xcomploc_vec = cellrecord(secondcelltype_mask ,1);
                ycomploc_vec = cellrecord(secondcelltype_mask ,2);
                dist_vec = sqrt((xcomploc_vec-xloc)^2+(ycomploc_vec-yloc)^2);
                dist_mask = dist>=1 & dist<=100.4999
                arraytarget_vec = round(dist_vec(dist_mask)*analysisdist/intervalnumber);
                count = accumarray(arraytarget_vec,1, [size(spatialsum,1),1]);
                spatialsum(:,1) = spatialsum(:,1)+count;
        end
    end
end
```

There may be some small errors in there since I don't have any data to test the code with but it should get ~10X speed up on the Matlab code.

From my experience with numpy I've noticed that swapping out for-loops for vectorized/matrix-based arithmetic has noticeable speed-ups as well.  However, without the shapes the shapes of all of your variables its hard to vectorize things.

Comment: For loops are not necessarily a problem.  This was true pre-JIT (Just In Time Compiler).  Use profiler to find problems.  NOTE:  I am not saying this solution is good or bad, just general advice on For Loops.

Comment: I just tested this one, had to do a little finagling to get the code working with the rest of my parameter but I think it's pretty close.  Unfortunately it dropped me to about 0.5x speed. Perhaps that has something to do with the JIT handling for loops well (I'm running 2009b)?

Comment: I stand corrected then ... although most of my Matlab hacking is on an old version pre-JIT.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid some of the `math.sqrt` calls by replacing the lines

```
                dist=math.sqrt((xcomploc-xloc)**2+(ycomploc-yloc)**2)
                dist=round(dist)
                if dist>=1 and dist<=analysisdist:
                     arraytarget=round(dist*analysisdist/intervalnumber)
```

with

```
                dist=(xcomploc-xloc)**2+(ycomploc-yloc)**2
                dist=round(dist)
                if dist>=1 and dist<=analysisdist_squared:
                     arraytarget=round(math.sqrt(dist)*analysisdist/intervalnumber)
```

where you have the line

```
 analysisdist_squared = analysis_dist * analysis_dist
```

outside of the main loop of your function.

Since `math.sqrt` is called in the innermost loop, you should have `from math import sqrt` at the top of the module and just call the function as `sqrt`.

<strike>I would also try replacing</strike>

```
                dist=(xcomploc-xloc)**2+(ycomploc-yloc)**2
```

with

```
                dist=(xcomploc-xloc)*(xcomploc-xloc)+(ycomploc-yloc)*(ycomploc-yloc)
```

There's a chance it will produce faster byte code to do multiplication rather than exponentiation.

I doubt these will get you all the way to MATLABs performance, but they should help reduce some overhead.

Comment: In Python `a ** 2` is often *faster* than `a * a`. Try `timeit`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multicore, you could maybe give the multiprocessing module a try and use multiple processes to make use of all the cores.

Instead of sqrt you could use x**0.5, which is, if I remember correct, slightly faster.